# Getting duplicate values in select box, Need to remove duplicate options from select box

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, select

> **I want to first remove the duplicate value from the deselected values
> in php or is it possible in jquery/javascript?**
>
> I'm working on edit page on my website where I need to show a **SELECT** box
> where some values should be selected and some should be not.

***I have following code after getting data from database***

```html
<select name="tour_category[]" multiple="multiple" style="height:300px;">
  <option value="1" selected>Family</option>
  <option value="3" selected>Wildlife</option>
  <option value="4" selected>Cuisine (Food Tours & Food Walks)</option>
  <option value="1">Family</option>
  <option value="1">Family</option>
  <option value="2">Religion & Spirituality</option>
  <option value="2">Religion & Spirituality</option>
  <option value="2">Religion & Spirituality</option>
  <option value="3">Wildlife</option>
  <option value="3">Wildlife</option>
  <option value="4">Cuisine (Food Tours & Food Walks)</option>
  <option value="4">Cuisine (Food Tours & Food Walks)</option>
  <option value="5">Boat Trips</option>
  <option value="5">Boat Trips</option>
  <option value="5">Boat Trips</option>
  <option value="6">Short Tours (Half Day tours/Walking Tours/Day Excursions)</option>
  <option value="6">Short Tours (Half Day tours/Walking Tours/Day Excursions)</option>
  <option value="6">Short Tours (Half Day tours/Walking Tours/Day Excursions)</option>
  <option value="7">Weekend Gateways</option>
  <option value="7">Weekend Gateways</option>
  <option value="7">Weekend Gateways</option>                      </select>
```

> ***but I need to show following output:***

```html
<select name="tour_category[]" multiple="multiple" style="height:200px;">
  <option value="1" selected>Family</option>
  <option value="2" selected>Religion & Spirituality</option>
  <option value="3" selected>Wildlife</option>
  <option value="4">Cuisine (Food Tours & Food Walks)</option>
  <option value="5">Boat Trips</option>
  <option value="6">Short Tours (Half Day tours/Walking Tours/Day Excursions</option>
  <option value="7">Weekend Gateways</option>
</select>
```

Comment: its better to have your php code too

Comment: Here is the php code : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57445368/marked-value-as-bold-when-it-exist-in-database

Answer (score 1):

If you want to achieve this, I suggest you show the `option` tags using a for loop or map, and you remove duplicates from the array your are mapping over. You can achieve this with ES6 by using `Set`.

So assume you have the following code :

```
const array = ['Family', 'Family', 'Wildelife', 'Wildlife'];
const uniqueSet= new Set(array);
const uniqueArray = [...uniqueSet];

//the new array will be ['Family', 'Wildlife']
```

Answer (score 1):

Add an attribute id="tour_category" in select tag and try

```
$(document).ready( function(){
    var a = new Array();
    $("#tour_category").children("option").each(function(x){
        test = false;
        b = a[x] = $(this).val();
        for (i=0;i<a.length-1;i++){
            if (b ==a[i]) {
               test =true;
            }
        }
        if (test) {
           $(this).remove();
        }
    })
});
```